# SAS Create a noise with random realization of a negative binomial distribution in a dataset

Tags: random, statistics, sas, simulation, noise

I’m working in SAS with a dataset such this:

[image]

I would like to introduce a variable, named “noised_y”, such this:

[image]

Every value of "noised_y" must be obtained, as a random realization of a negative binomial distribution of mean ugual to the correspondent value of y.

May you suggest a Sas procedure to create a random noise as this?

Thank you very much

G

Comment: What is ugual ?

Comment: Are you just asking how to use the RAND() function?  https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p0fpeei0opypg8n1b06qe4r040lv.htm#p1qe4v505yn2urn15t5raec2pl1i  Can you show the code you tried and explain in what way it did not do what you want?